# Stop and Remove route from camel context

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, karaf

I have multiple threads running in camel context. Each thread is accumulating data. I'm unable to stop route in camel context. Here is my code:

```
public void stopThread(String routeId, CamelContext context) {
    System.out.println("Stop status: " + context.stopRoute("thread1", 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, false));
    System.out.println("Remove status: " + context.removeRoute("thread1"));
}
```

I also tried the following:

```
public void stopThread(String routeId, CamelContext context) {
    context.stopRoute("thread1");
    System.out.println("Remove status: " + context.removeRoute("thread1"));
}
```

Output:

```
Stop status: false
Remove status: false
```

And I see that the threads are accumulating data. I don't know how else to achieve this programmatically. I'm using camel 2.16.2. Any help would be appreciated.

It works fine when I stop and start the camel context:

```
context.stop();
context.start();
```

Comment: Just to clarify - in `context.stopRoute("thread1");` `"thread1"` is the Route ID, correct? Also, how are you calling `stopThread()`? Did you make sure that the `CamelContext` you're passing in is the same one the route is registered to?

Comment: Yes, thread1 is the route Id. I'm calling stopThread() from a different method. camel context is different from the registered one. Thank you so much!

Comment: "camel context is different from the registered one" -- this is no good. The camel context you pass is has to be the one that the route is registered to. You should debug this (set a breakpoint) to make sure that the route is registered there. Otherwise, there's no way for the Camel Context to stop the route if it doesn't know about it.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Thank you !@Khaled

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Apache Camel 4.3.0 with multiple threads.

Remove status gave me: `false`. I tried to debug it and get the route by id, it worked:

```java
getContext().getRoute("MyRouteId")
```

gave me my route back successfully.

After checking the context:

```java
getContext().getRoute("MyRouteId").getCamelContext()
```

it seemed to be the same as I where I am trying to delete from, otherwise this will not work.

Just removing it

```java
getContext().removeRoute(getContext().getRoute("[2] Test").getId())
```

seemed not to work.

Anyways, I figured out I would need to stop the route beforehand **from the same context** (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.java as stated in the JavaDocs).

```
getContext().getRouteController().stopRoute("MyRouteId");
```

Afterwards I was able to remove it.

If you still struggle, please repeat these steps.

1. Check whether the route is available in the context
2. Stop it, if not already done
3. Remove it

Hope it helped.
Kind regards!